# Utility/Sniffer to track internet traffic/speed of all PCs in local network

Tags: network-monitoring

It doesn't matter if utility is for Ubuntu or for Windows XP/7, just need to see what pc is using the most traffic in local network.

Probably some spammer etc on that pc.

Need to get rid of that, before calling to my ISP.

Comment: What about wireshark??

Comment: Does it have graphs or something like that? Or overall packets sent/received by specific ip?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wireshark will work if you can span a gateway connection in order to see *all* the PCs traffic.  Otherwise, you'll only see your own.

If your PCs support SNMP, I think your best bet will be a tool like [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/).  This way you run Cacti on a central PC/server, which then polls the other PCs for interface information and graphs the resulting interfaces for comparison.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is the superb tool for doing this. And [HERE](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/networktools1.htm) is the list of all the tools you'l ever need, such as:

- BWM - BandWidth Monitor
- port scanner
- A tool to send magic Wake-on-LAN packets
- script that quickly measures network device throughput
- etc...

I also found a lot of bandwidth monitoring tools for Linux [HERE](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/bandwidth-monitoring-tools-for-linux.html).

Answer (score 1):

+1 on wireshark that really is a wonderful tool (and @Beck you can use Statistics -> Conversations or Statistics-> Endpoints to get a summary of traffic).

You may also find [Etherape](http://etherape.sourceforge.net/) to be useful. That gives you a realtime graphical representation of where most traffic is coming/going from.

However do bear in mind that whichever tool you use to measure the traffic you will likely need to measure it from your gateway/router because any one individual machine will not see the traffic for the rest of the network due to network switching and various other factors. If you don't have a graphical interface on your gateway machine you could grab a packet dump using *tcpdump* or *tshark*

Comment: Better to spell EtherApe, not Etherape (for obvious reasons).

Answer (score -1):

Iptraf is a great tool for monitoring LAN Traffic as well as individual traffic,

The tool is handy and could be viewed form terminal itself.

For advanced monitoring i suggest wireshark

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! This would be a better answer if you were to provide installation instructions. Please edit and add that information. Thank you!